# Image seen when viewer is closer to lens than convergence point

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

[image]

In the following diagram, The human will see the real image, P', standing where they are. But, what if the human is closer to the mirror? Then P' is behind them so they clearly can't see P'. Do they see a blurred image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't see a picture at all from your object. but they will see an imaginary picture of them selfs.  Just trie it out!

Comment: But don't the light rays from P still enter our eye?

Comment: Yes, but from all the objects behind your head, so sure you get also some rays from the point you painted, but you do not "see" it not even blurred. Why not try it out?